# Show app name on Tile update

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am developing a simple app which updates its tile time to time.

I need my app to show its **name** on the tile all the time. Therefore, I set the `Show Name` to `All Logos` in my app manifest.

The problem is that when my app updates its tile (using `TileSquareBlock` tile template) the app name would be replaced by app Logo.

How can I keep my app name on tile after updating?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the tile notification XML, specify "name" as the value for the [branding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br212854.aspx) attribute.  Using this attribute, one can specify whether the tile shows the app logo, the name, or nothing.