# How to display text on Windows 8 SecondaryTile?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I want to create a SecondaryTile  which should display some text rather than a logo. How should I do that?

I tried setting displayName of SecondaryTile object to the text, but that displays the text as the name of secondary tile. I don't want that. **I want the my entire text to be displayed on the secondary tile without any logo**.

C# code would be appreciated...

Thanks

Comment: please provide the code you use for creating secondary tile..

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701597.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To provide large text on the secondary tile, you can do one of two things:

1. Embed the text in the image provided for the secondary tile
2. Use tile notifications to update the tile

Tile notifications are probably a better option. With [tile notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465439.aspx), your tile can be updated using one of the [tile visual templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh761491.aspx).

Tile notifications can be sent to secondary tiles using the `CreateTileUpdaterForSecondaryTile` API (in place of the `CreateTileUpdaterForApplication` shown in the [tiles sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/App-tiles-and-badges-sample-5fc49148)).

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked. But there is one more problem. I'm using [TileWideText04](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh761491.aspx#TileWideText04) XML template and I have set the text of its node. However, instead of showing text in 3 lines on secondary tile, only 1 line of text is displayed and remaining part is occupied by the logo of the app. **How can i remove this logo, so that text can be displayed in 3 lines on Secondary Tile?**

Comment: ^The following is the code that I have used to create SecondaryTile:                `logo = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Logo.png");
                toBeCreatedTile = new SecondaryTile(appbarTileId,
                                        shortName,
                                        displayName,
                                        tileActivationArguments,
                                        TileOptions.None,
                                        logo,
                                        logo
                                        );`

Comment: Set the branding attribute in the XML to "none".  http://stackoverflow.com/a/12331465/1656796