# Appname in a Tile - update

Tags: microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, visual-studio-2012, winrt-xaml

Hello I developed an application with Tile Update. 
When I look it in my metro, there is no Application Name, but only the small logo from the app-manifest. Is it possible to show my app-name in my Tile-Updater?

Comment: Looks to be a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/a/12331465/1656796

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

There are [multiple variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br212854.aspx) you can set in a `Tile` update. One of them is the thing you are looking for called `Branding`. Set that to `name` so your app name will be shown on `Tile` update.

Example:

```
<binding template=""TileSquareBlock"" branding=""name"">
    <text id=""1""></text>
    <text id=""2""></text>
</binding>
```