# How to remove the app name from a Windows Store App tile?

Tags: c#, windows-8

My tile already contains the title of my application. How can I set the title of the tile to nothing? When I just put a space or nothing in the DisplayName (Appmanifest) I get the following error:

```
App manifest validation failed. Value of attribute '/Package/Applications/Application/VisualElements/@DisplayName' cannot start or end with whitespace.
```

(The guidelines say it is possible:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465403.aspx#using_default_tiles)

Comment: The guidelines say that its possible and that you should do it.. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465403.aspx#using_default_tiles

Comment: Related question for Live Tile updates: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12328964/1656796

Answer (score 2):

Got it! In the appxmanifest just change the ShowName to "noLogos":