# How to remove app name and add background color from/to windows app tile in Config.xml of Visual Studio 2015 Tools for Apache Cordova

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, win-universal-app, taco

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Tools for Apache Cordova to build a multi-platform app . Now I want to do the following

1. Remove the name on my app tile, since my app tile image already
   contains its name
2. Add a background color to my app tile

Now I have already come across answers like,
[how-do-i-remove-the-app-name-from-my-flipping-live-tile-on-windows-phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24078543/how-do-i-remove-the-app-name-from-my-flipping-live-tile-on-windows-phone)
and
[how-to-remove-the-app-name-from-a-windows-store-app-tile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13217628/how-to-remove-the-app-name-from-a-windows-store-app-tile)

But, I think they are for `C# / XAML`, So, none of them gives a clear answer to **"what to write"** and **"where to write"** in config.xml file of VS Taco.

That said, also it will be quite helpful if someone can point me to a documentation which lists all the possible things can go into Config.xml. I have already looked into [cordova documentation which is here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/index.html), but only gives an overview and also contains nothing much useful for VS Taco.

Please let me know, if anyone needs any further inputs from my side. But I truly feel that there needs to be a stronger and more detailed documentation on **"how to do things"** with VS Taco.

Thanks you.

Comment: In case everything else fails, try providing a custom app manifest file in the res/native folder as described [here](http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/configure-app/#Configuration). Anyway I guess there has to be a better solution , but I can't find a good piece of documentation on this either :(

Comment: Yeah I have also looked into that option but I want to explore the capabilities of Config.xml more... Anyway, thanks for the comment :)