# Live Tiles with periodic update - logo not visible

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime

I want to update Live Tiles periodically.

```
var tileUpdater = TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication();
tileUpdater.StartPeriodicUpdate(new Uri("http://myurl/tile.xml"), PeriodicUpdateRecurrence.HalfHour);
```

But I am not able to make the small logo visible in the lower left corner.

I also tried setting the branding attribute in the xml source. The following line enabled the short app name.

```
<tile>
  <visual branding="name">
    <binding template="TileWideImageAndText02" >
      <image id="1" src="http://someurl/image.jpg" alt="Demo"/>
      <text id="1">line 1</text>
      <text id="2">line 2</text>
    </binding>
  </visual>
</tile>
```

But setting branding to "logo" had no effect.

The small logo is of course set in the manifast and the image has a build action of "Content".

Any ideas, why the logo doesn't show on my live tiles?

cheers!

Comment: Related to the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12328964/1656796

Comment: Does the logo show on the tile before live tile updates are provided?

Comment: No - logo never Shows on the tile.

Comment: Can you try using the settings in the app manifest and the logo from the App tiles sample?  http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/App-tiles-and-badges-sample-5fc49148

Comment: That's strange... The sample doesn't work for me either! 
Scenario 5 allows to set the branding attribute. When I set it to Logo, it reserves space for the small Icon, but the lower left corner is still empty. >:o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suddenly the icon appears whithout any changes. Seems to be a bug.

Answer (score 0):

In the tile notification XML, specify "logo" as the value for the [branding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br212854.aspx) attribute.  Using the branding attribute, one can specify whether the tile shows the app logo, the name, or nothing.

Comment: Thanks! But as I wrote in my question: <visual branding="logo"> had no effect. :(