# Live tiles in windows 8 hide small logo image

Tags: windows-8, winrt-xaml

Hi am using the following code, the live tiles works fine but what i found the small logo is always there on there left bottom of the tile, how can i get rid of it? see [this](http://postimage.org/image/nm19nlf8t/)

```
 XmlDocument tileXml = TileUpdateManager.GetTemplateContent(TileTemplateType.TileWideImageAndText01);
        XmlDocument squareTileXml = TileUpdateManager.GetTemplateContent(TileTemplateType.TileSquarePeekImageAndText01);

        XmlNodeList textElements = tileXml.GetElementsByTagName("text");
        textElements[0].AppendChild(tileXml.CreateTextNode(_serviceOrderItems.Count.ToString()));

        XmlNodeList imageElements = tileXml.GetElementsByTagName("image");
        XmlElement imageElement = (XmlElement)imageElements[0];
        imageElement.SetAttribute("src", "ms-appx:///Assets/Image310X150.jpg");
        imageElement.SetAttribute("alt", "Aker Solutions");

        XmlNodeList squareImageElements = squareTileXml.GetElementsByTagName("image");
        XmlElement squareImageElement = (XmlElement)squareImageElements.Item(0);
        squareImageElement.SetAttribute("src", "ms-appx:///Assets/Image150X150.jpg");
        squareImageElement.SetAttribute("alt", "Aker Solutions");

        IXmlNode subnode = tileXml.ImportNode(squareTileXml.GetElementsByTagName("binding")[0], true);
        tileXml.GetElementsByTagName("visual")[0].AppendChild(subnode);

        TileNotification tile = new TileNotification(tileXml);
        TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().Update(tile);
```

Comment: This question is a variant of http://stackoverflow.com/a/12331465/1656796.  Set the branding attribute to "none" on the visual element (to apply to both the square and wide content) or the binding element.

Comment: Thanks Nathan, added following lines   
            XmlElement visualElement = tileXml.GetElementsByTagName("visual")[0] as XmlElement;
            
            visualElement.SetAttribute("branding", "None");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set branding="none"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tile>
<visual lang="en-US">
    <binding template="TileSquareImage" branding="none">
        <image id="1" src="http://abc..../xx.png"/>
    </binding>
    <binding template="TileWideImageAndText01" branding="none">
        <image id="1" src="http://abc.../yy.png"/>
        <text id="1">Test message</text>
    </binding>
</visual>
</tile>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

Just noticed the comments that you can set the [branding attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br212857.aspx) on the visual or binding node.

```
tileXml.getElementsByTagName('visual')[0].setAttribute('branding', 'none');
```

---

There is a [small logo property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.startscreen.secondarytile.smalllogo.aspx) on the tile that controls this. However the documentation states:

> If this image is not provided, the small logo of this secondary tile's parent app is used.

Since a small logo is also required for your app there is no way to turn it off. A workaround is to set the small logo to a completely transparent 30 by 30 pixel png.

```
var tile = new Windows.UI.StartScreen.SecondaryTile(newTileID, newTileShortName, newTileDisplayName, TileActivationArguments, newTileOptions, uriLogo);
tile.smallLogo = new Windows.Foundation.Uri("ms-appx:///images/smallLogoBlank.png");
```