# How can I remove live tile title in a Windows Phone 8.1 application?

Tags: c#, xml, live-tile, windows-phone-8.1

I'm building a wide live tile using TileWide310x150Image template in a BackgroundTask, which should show only a wide image, no text or else.

This is the template I'm using:

```
<tile>
 <visual>
  <binding template="TileWideImage">
   <image id="1" src="image1.png" />
  </binding>  
 </visual>
</tile>
```

However, application's name is still there and I can't find anything to remove it in the Manifest as it was possible on Windows Phone 7 and 8.

Is there any way to remove it?

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328964/show-app-name-on-tile-update/12331465#12331465

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the tile notification XML, specify "none" as the value for the [branding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br212854.aspx) attribute.  Using this attribute, one can specify whether the tile shows the app logo, the name, or nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck the checkboxes in Visual Assets tab in the package.appxmanifest file, that removed the title for me. However it didn't do that for the TileSquare150x150IconWithBadge template for some odd reason.