# App name is not displayed in tile (start screen) windows phone

Tags: windows-phone, windows-mobile, live-tile

I've inputted "Display name" in Manifest file but when I built the app to my real device (Windows Mobile 10), the app name was not displayed in the tile (small, medium, large sizes).
What should I do to fix this?
Thanks.

Following is my manifest configuration:

```
<Properties>
<DisplayName>MyApp</DisplayName>
...
</Properties>

<m3:VisualElements DisplayName="MyApp" Square150x150Logo="Assets\Logo.png" Square44x44Logo="Assets\SmallLogo.png" Description="MyApp.WindowsPhone" ForegroundText="light" BackgroundColor="transparent">
    <m3:DefaultTile Wide310x150Logo="Assets\WideLogo.png" Square71x71Logo="Assets\Square71x71Logo.png">
    </m3:DefaultTile>
    <m3:SplashScreen Image="Assets\SplashScreen.png" />
    <m3:InitialRotationPreference>
      <m3:Rotation Preference="portrait" />
    </m3:InitialRotationPreference>
  </m3:VisualElements>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23128091/how-can-i-remove-live-tile-title-in-a-windows-phone-8-1-application

Comment: Thanks. Different question but I've found the answer